# Generate Multiple Files After aggregating in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have created a route that

1. reads xml file
2. split it
3. aggregate it on basis of categories.After aggregation i am receiving arrays i-e array1 for category1, array2 for category2.
4. When i write the file it results out to to print any random array from data set.

Question: How to print multiple files on basis of number of arrays generated by aggregator?

```
                    from("file:C:\\Users\\Desktop?fileName=books.xml&noop=true")
                    .split(xpath("/books/book"))
                    .process(new MyProcessor())
                    .setHeader("category", xpath("/book/@category").stringResult())
                    .aggregate(header("category"), new SetAggregationStrategy()).completionTimeout(500)
                    .process(new MyProcessor())
                    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                    .to("file:C:\\Users\\Desktop\\New")
                    .end();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just **overwrite the same file with every new aggregation**. To avoid this, you have to give every aggregation another (dynamic) filename to write it to.

For example to set [categoryname].xml as filename for every aggreation you can use

```
.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("${headers.category}.xml"))
```

Exchange.FILE_NAME is a Camel constant for the filename header and with the [Simple expression language](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html) you can concatenate the category name you set as header in your route and a static file suffix.

If the same category is aggregated over an over again, you have to extend the filename further (otherwise a category overwrites its previous file). For example with a timestamp or similar.